# could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1

Tags: 11.04, updates, disk, disk-management

I have just had a major issue with my Ubuntu 11.04 Natty which I think is going to end up in a reinstall :-(

This is problem one of two so I've put them as two questions.

For some unknown reason I had a Distribution update on my Laptop yesterday which for all intend and purposes did nothing. 
No major version changes except in Evolution and LibreOffice plus some of the GNOME environment (my other question).

Now, whenever I boot my machine I receive this message

```
could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 M for manual S for skip
```

What would have caused this error and what on earth is Cryptswap1?

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c3cff8dd-1bf2-4618-8801-761b335c8d38 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

`sudo blkid | grep swap`

`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: TYPE:"swap"`

Crypttab
`# <target name>    <source device>     <key file>  <options>`

`ls -l /dev/mapper`
`total 0`
`crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 2011-08-16 05:28 control`

`Filename               Type        Size    Used    Priority`

`/dev/sda5                               partition  1038332 86760   -1`

Comment: `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` is your encrypted swap, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/53242/check-if-partition-is-encrypted/53244#53244

Comment: According to that post my drive is NOT encypted so why is it trying to mount a some-what virtual drive?

Comment: Please include the output of `/etc/fstab` in your question.

Comment: Is there no comments (lines starting with `#`) in your `/etc/fstab`? If there is, it's important to include them here so we can se what's commented out and what's not. We need the *exact* contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: According to your `/etc/fstab` your swap is encrypted. Please also include the output of `sudo blkid | grep swap` in your question.

Comment: Done N.N. hope it helps

Comment: I've got a similar setup to yours and I get the message too. I'm also looking for a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `/etc/fstab` file, the `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` entry is there, which is why Ubuntu tries to mount it on boot. If you don't use encrypted partitions, that line shouldn't be there. For some reason the line created by the Ubuntu installer got commented out too. So just change (in `/etc/fstab`):

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

to

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**IMPORTANT:** Before you restart, make sure you check that `fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601` is actually `/dev/sda5` by running:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601
```

It should say something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2011-08-16 08:28 /dev/disk/by-uuid/fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601 -> ../../sda5
```

The `sda5` part at the end is the important part. Once you are sure the UUID matches the partition number, run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and make sure that `/dev/sda5` is a swap partition.

Then just restart and that's it :) Hope this helps.

Comment: A question about the *IMPORTANT* part.  What should I do when the `ls` command doesn't have that output, but instead says: `cannot access: No such file or directory`?

Answer (score 4):

Like Chen Xiao-Long discribed in his answer, you have to remove "cryptswap" line in `/etc/fstab`. Then you uncomment previously commented swap line so end of file looks like that:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fe10641d-a928-479e-ab3a-b0706b97b601 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

To verify UUID and filesystem type (with cleaned cache), run:

```
~$ sudo blkid /dev/sda5 -c /dev/null
```

To try your new configuration immediately you have to reload `/etc/fstab`:

```
~$ sudo mount -a
```

Apart from that I have no idea why an (release?) upgrade causes this error.

---

#### Old version:

Request:

- `/etc/crypttab`
- `ls -l /dev/mapper`
- `lvscan` (only LVM)
- `fdisk -l`
- `cat /proc/swaps`
- why is your UUID line of swap partition commented?
- is UUID output of `blkid` command same as in `/etc/fstab` (or is that all output of `blkid`)?

#### Temporay fix:

To suppress this message on boot you can add mount option "nobootwait" or comment line in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: UUID from Fstab is 100% as is. The comment is, i believe in relation to the comment above stating that my crypt was on SDA5 during installation. I questioned this as well considering the installation has not changed and I only have one drive split into 2 partitions via the installation. The second line of my coding is the blkid which, as you can see shows no UUID.