# help with: "dev/mapper/cryptswap1 has no valid partition"

Tags: 12.04

I'm a new user guessing I messed something up on install or while I've been messing around.  This message keeps popping up and seems to be the root of a few problems I'm having.

What kind of problem is it? I'd like to know if you know.  And of course how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching and found this [**page**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56843/could-not-mount-dev-mapper-cryptswap1).

1. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo blkid | grep swap
   ```

   It will show something like:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="6afe8dec-350c-424e-b902-18e7a6a0f227" TYPE="swap"
   ```
2. Copy `6afe8dec-350c-424e-b902-18e7a6a0f227` and type this command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
3. Replace this code and delete the `#` at first Line.

   **old:**

   ```
   #UUID=0a69433c-52f7-40a4-8baa-71ac1ae1cb07 none  swap sw   0   0
   ```

   **new:**

   ```
   UUID=6afe8dec-350c-424e-b902-18e7a6a0f227 none   swap sw   0   0
   ```

Comment: I have the same problem. I get a new error now saying that the partition by the name of the copied UUID could not be mounted.