# cryptswap1 issue when booting 12.04

Tags: boot, mount

When I'm starting my laptop which is running 12.04, most times recently I get a message saying:

> `its taking a while to mount dev/mapper/cryptswap1`

If I want to wait or skip it.

When I skip, nothing negative seems to happen, but just wanted to check to see if its something I should resolve.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56843/could-not-mount-dev-mapper-cryptswap1)
Do you use encrypted partitions?