# Cryptswap boot error - can't mount?

Tags: mount, encryption, swap

I believe i have my swap set up but am not sure because on start up it says that it is something along the lines of **"could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 M for manual S for skip"**. But it appears to be mounted? I have already [tried this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56843/could-not-mount-dev-mapper-cryptswap1) with no success.

When i run `free -m` the output is:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3887        769       3117          0         54        348
-/+ buffers/cache:        366       3520
Swap:         4026          0       4026
```

and `sudo bklid` is:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="9fb3ccd6-3732-4989-bfa4-e943a09f1153" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="bd9fe154-8621-48b3-95d2-ae5c91f373fd" TYPE="swap"
```

and `cat /etc/crypttab` is:

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda5 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

my `/etc/fstab` is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9fb3ccd6-3732-4989-bfa4-e943a09f1153 /               ext4    
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=bb0e378e-8742-435a-beda-ae7788a7c1b0 none            swap    
sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

`cat /proc/swaps` output is:

```
Filename             Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0                               partition   4123644 0   -1
```

**Is my swap not setup correctly or how can i fix my boot message?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I happened to stumble upon this problem for 3 different releases of Ubuntu on two different computers. While most of the time the swap-partition was mounted despite the warning message, sometimes the GUI refused to start upon boot completion because of it.

Here's what I did as a workaround:

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Search for the line that reads:

`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

Now enter the value `noauto` right after `sw` (separated by a comma), so it looks like this:

`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw,noauto 0 0`

Save and exit. This way, your swap partition won't be mounted *while booting*, thus the warning message won't appear or even hinder the login screen to appear.

Now type in a terminal

`gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

and enter the following lines **before the entry** `exit 0`:

`sleep 10`

`swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1`

If there's no entry `exit 0`, you'll have to enter it right beneath those two lines. 
Save and exit again. This will tell your system to wait 10 seconds after login to mount your encrypted swap partition.

Reboot your system. You should not get the warning message any longer. After login, wait some time, then open up a terminal again and type

`free -m`

Your output should look something like this:

> fuzzyq@Samsung-R710:~$ free -m
>
> ```
>               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
>
>  Mem:          3949       3806        143          0         86       1783
>
>  -/+ buffers/cache:       1936       2013
>
>  Swap:         4095          0       4095
> ```
>
> The last line is the important one. If there's a positive value showing for total swap, your swap partition was being mounted successfully.

Comment: Thanks so much this finally fixed my problem and its mounting correctly!

Comment: Glad it worked, congratulation!

Comment: I tried this on the (upcoming) Ubuntu 14.04 and unfortunately the procedure did not help -- the swap got created at the last step with `swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1` but it did not get mounted after reboot. It seems to me the workaround may not be able to help, due to issues described in this [Launchpad bugreport discussion related to the issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1153661/comments/5) (caveat: a technical discussion).

Comment: This answer might be 1.5 years old, but still works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't mount swap file systems. You can however check that they're in use with:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

which will show you all block devices configured to be used as swap.

Comment: I edited my op to clarify my question. I want to fix the boot message I am getting. Not sure if `cat /proc/swaps` will help in that but i added it to my post

Comment: Is it supposed to be `sda5` or is it ok that my `cat /proc/swaps` is `dm-0`