# Cant mount cryptswap1 ?

Tags: mount, filesystem, encryption

From the reading I've done, it seems it's having issues mounting the encrypted files. 
The guys here:
[could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56843/could-not-mount-dev-mapper-cryptswap1)
Seem to be suggesting how to fix it, but I am new to Linux and have NO idea how to do any of that. 
Can anyone walk me through how to edit that file?

Or should I just reinstal? Is there a way to reinstall and keep my programs? 
I do have separate partitions for boot root home and swap

Running Acer Aspire 5750 Intel Core i3 4gb ram
Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter `su` then type in your pass word and next enter `gedit /etc/fstab` the file will open and you can edit it accordingly, save and close gedit. Type `exit` to exit from root and continue with the rest of the directions given.

Comment: where do I hit control+alt+t tho? do i go into the advanced menu and hit C to open the console? where it says grub?  I'm wondering where I need to be to even open the terminal. It can't be while its stuck loading...

Comment: ok i got to the prompt, but when i use gedit /etc/fstab  it says gedit:901  could not open X display

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gtk-warning-**-cannot-open-display-when-i-su-28120/)