# Ensure swap encryption, add /var encryption, full HD encryption

Tags: encryption, swap, ecryptfs

1. I encrypted my swap with ecryptfs, but sometimes when I boot during the splash screen it says the swap is not encrypted, then it disappears. How can I check if it is encrypted?
2. Only my $HOME files are encrypted. What can be done about the information that leaks into system directories like /var/log? To where does it leak? How can I clean them systematically?
3. Supposing the answer to number 2 is that it leaks a lot, is full HD encryption a better option to solve this? If yes, what free program to use, since ecryptfs does not have this option?

Comment: That is three different questions. This site works better if you ask one question at the time so I suggest that you split them up. You should search the site before asking questions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/53242/check-if-partition-is-encrypted may answer your first question.

Comment: It doesn't answer number 1 because to check it unlogged I have to enter either as root or guess. I already did that, and root sees all, and guest sees the typical x on the folder, because the user has no access no matter if encrypted or not, so it does not give me information.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clarify it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You should really ask one question at a time, instead of 3 together.*

You can see your swap partitions with:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

And you can see your device-mapper encrypted swap partition configuration with:

```
cat /etc/crypttab
```

As long as all of your swap partitions listed in `/proc/swaps` are also configured for encryption in `/etc/crypttab`, you're in good shape.

Home Directory Encryption is only meant to protect the data you store in your home directory, and is intended as a balance among security, usability, and performance.  Various bits of system information "leak" (as you say) to `/etc` (configuration files), `/var` (varying program information and log files) and `/tmp` (temporary files).  If you want to encrypt all of that, you should use full disk encryption, which you can configure at installation using the [Ubuntu Alternate Install media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemOnIntrepid).