# Check to see if ecryptfs worked

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I have been trying to encrypt my home directory using the instructions here: http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/, but it failed part of the way through after running the command `sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u eddy`. Here are the last few lines output before the programme terminated:

```
android_workspace/MyFirstApp/src/com/eddytheb/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java
      1,463 100%    4.91kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#200443, to-chk=1/221932)
android_workspace/MyFirstApp/src/com/eddytheb/myfirstapp/MainActivity.java
      1,025 100%    3.34kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#200444, to-chk=0/221932)
information/
preprobe/
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I've had a look for "previous errors", but I can't see anything, it looks to me like there's basically a line like the following for every file, but I cannot see back to the beginning of the command because it has filled my terminal as far back as I can scroll.

```
Pictures/2016/Photos2016Edited/IMG_20160720_124505.jpg
  2,118,107 100%    3.05MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#197821, ir-chk=2133/221314)
```

So I'd like to know, did the encryption work? Did it work for some files, fail for others and then stop? And if it failed what can I do? Is it safe to just try running the command again or will that result in some double-encryption issues? Perhaps I should just recover from my recent backup before trying again.

MORE INfO

Other info that suggests that the process worked:

After `sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u eddy` failed I logged back in as eddy and two things happened that suggested something had changed: first, I was instructed to re-install dropbox; and second, I was instructed to view and make a note of my ecryptfs passphrase. I did both.

From my home directory `ls -A /home` shows that I have an .ecryptfs directory, and that /home/.ecryptfs/eddy/.Private/ is full of files like 'ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FXbO-DbnsIQgsUSOhExSAtVeUT6iVjljYTA-ze4e4UzGGHP1E0fZajIdzrID0q-TjIKzj75kD4Y-Ga6-'

If I do `df -T` then I see that my home directory is mounted; I have a line that reads:

```
/home/.ecryptfs/eddy/.Private ecryptfs 957172372 454736500 453791216  51% /home/eddy
```

Other info that suggests that the process failed:

If I log out of eddy and log in as my temporary user with administrative rights, then `sudo ls -lA /home/eddy/` shows my entire home directory. I was expecting just 4 files, as suggested by the answer to this question here: [Check if partition is encrypted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53242/check-if-partition-is-encrypted)

Answer (score 3):

A little bit of investigation, and I have confirmed that the encryption process worked. I created an Ubuntu boot usb drive, and booted my laptop from that, and when I tried to access the 'eddy' home directory it contained only the four items; Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop, .ecryptfs, .Private and README.txt. While if I looked in the home directory of another account then it contains all of the usual directories.