# Encrypting /home in 16.04; got 'unable to find shell'; Dropbox missing

Tags: 16.04, encryption, home-directory, dropbox, ecryptfs

I encrypted my /home (after install) after a many months of using Ubuntu today, and a the end of the encryption, I got an error message that a few folks have gotten:

rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23

This was mentioned here:

[Check to see if ecryptfs worked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866410/check-to-see-if-ecryptfs-worked#866830)

Now, after logging out of the temporary user (to encrypt my home directory), after logging back in, I noticed two things:

1) When the screen comes up to do the passphase bit, I get an 'unable to to find shell'.  When I open a regular terminal, I can give the ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase without a problem.

2) Dropbox didn't fire up when I logged in; I'm wondering if this is all related.

Of course, I've backed everything up, so I'm not panicking too much, but I'd like to know what has gone on, and what my next steps should be.

Addendum:

When I logged out, and logged back in, things weren't quite right; for example, the Unity 'Search my computer' wouldn't return any applications, and the screen seemed to be sized incorrectly (I work with a laptop and docking station with a larger screen).

After rebooting, things seemed to be OK.   If this means things are working, great, but perhaps this description can help in some way.